# Problems with virtual eth interfaces on an Mac 10.6 OD Master

Tags: domain-name-system, mac-osx-server, osx-snow-leopard, opendirectory

I've been trying to setup multiple virtual interfaces (virtual ethernet ports) on a 10.6.8 OS X Server - this server is our Open Directory master. I want to set up additional IPs on the server because I have a website that needs SSL and our Kerio mail server already uses SSL on the default port.

So I go into System Preferences, duplicate the Ethernet connection, change the IP. I add an A record for the new IP, enable the website to point to the new record, restart, etc. The new website works fine.

The problem is that now the machine thinks its main IP is the new IP and new interface, not the original one. Under Settings/Network in Server Admin, the new IP/DNS name is the one listed in bold. Opening a local terminal session also uses the new DNS name as the host. What worries me most is that if I do a `sudo changeip -checkhostname` to check Open Directory, it reports a mismatch between the old name and new name. Running the suggested command to fix it changes the DNS name of the new IP to the DNS name of the old IP, creating duplicates in Server Admin. That seems wrong ;). How should I properly set up virtual ethernet interfaces while keeping the OD installation safe, or there's a different way of solving the SSL/multiple IP problem, I'd love to hear it.

Thanks!

Comment: Is running virtual interfaces on an OD master just a bad idea?